# Next.js monorepo: multiple apps on subdomains vs. one app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, monorepo, nx.dev

I just started using [nx.dev](https://nx.dev/) to migrate from a single app repo to a monorepo as I have added a very basic static documentation app to the mix which is deployed to a subdomain `docs.company.com`.

My main application is currently deployed to main route `company.com`. However, one could think of it as different apps as well where there is `app1`, `app2` and `admin` for example. I do like the idea of having everything as a single application as it can be easily deployed with nx and Vercels monorepo support.

I am just not sure what the go to approach is here. Of course, I could split up the main app into multiple apps and deploy them independently to subdomains such as:

- admin.company.com
- app1.company.com
- app2.company.com

If understood correctly, I could also use [multi zones](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones) support if I do not like subdomains and use one domain instead.

This main app, that could logically be split up in multiple apps is non public and authentication is required. It is completely client side rendered while apollo client is used to interatct with the GraphQL API. This API server also sets an `http-only` JWT cookie for authentication. I am quite sure I could mitigate the issue with subdomains in this regard by setting the domain cookie setting, such that the cookie is also valid for subdomains.

However, as the cookie is `http-only` I cannot access it from the client and need to keep track of the logged in status in my global state mangement (which is overmind.js). Splitting up the app would add some extra complexity to persist global state between subdomain apps.

I am not sure whether this is worth it or if it is better sticking to the one app approach. I would love to hear your opinion and maybe I have forgotten some major issues. Some questions that come to my mind:

- What are the advantages and disadvantages of using subdomains?
- Is it more preferable to use multi zones and only one app?
- How could the auth/global state issues be solved if switching to multiple apps?

What are your thoughts?